# error parsing date

Tags: java, date

```
String dateString="2001/03/09";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
System.out.println("Converted string to date : " + convertedDate);
```

i get output as follows:
Converted string to date : Tue Jan 09 00:03:00 IST 2001

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5):

Use `MM` instead of `mm` for months - `mm` means minutes, not months.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

See the API documentation of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Still doesnt work, why does it give me the result in that format when i clearly want the result as yyyy/MM/dd

Comment: @Joy.. You are giving that format for parsing your String. If you want to print the Date in a required format, you would need to format it back.

Comment: i am actually using a getter and setter method so i need to set the date in that format.

Comment: @Joy `Date` objects do not have a format by themselves. The `Date` object is just the value, just like an `int` is just a number, without an inherent format. You specify the format when you convert the `Date` to a `String` or vice versa, using a `DateFormat` object. So, you cannot "set the date in that format" - that just doesn't make sense.

Comment: From the above code, after i replace mm to MM, can you tell me what should be the output?

Comment: The output should be: `Fri Mar 09 00:00:00 IST 2001`

Comment: so how do i write the code so that convertedDate will be 2001/03/09. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: You cannot, because `convertedDate` is a `Date` object, and it does not have a format by itself, as I explained. Instead of trying to "set the date in that format", which is impossible, you should format the date with a `SimpleDateFormat` at the place where the date is displayed.

Comment: `System.out.println("Converted string to date : " + dateFormat.format(convertedDate));`

Comment: Okay, i had to save the date in a database, that's why i was so much into converting the date in the specific format.